# resource for scheduling algorithms in cloud computing

Tags: java, cloud

I am looking for some book and resource about architectural and structure of cloud computing.
I want to know about scheduling algorithms in cloud computing  and implement one of them with Java programming language. First I have to know about cloud computing then I have to research about D.O and cloud computing scheduling and implement one of them with Java programing language I want good resource for this project.

Comment: Your question is too vague. Scheduling algorithm used by what for what? And what is that to do with computer *programming*, which is what this Q&A site is about?

Comment: scheduling algorithm for job scheduling in cloud computing system  and i have to  implementing one of  algorithm of  scheduling  (job scheduling )I searched and i knew i have to know  how can i implementing genetic algorithm for job scheduling in distributed operating system if any body knows about this algorithm it means sample code of it  please  Gide me